# how to close activity from event

Tags: android

I have the following code

```
public class DevClick implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) { ... }
```

This is called from ListView from the activity.
I want in that event that the caller activity will close. how can I get the activity from this event??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) { finish(); }
```

just only call finish function for closing activity.

Comment: This will only work if the DevClick class is a inner class of the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a custom constructor for your class an pass the activity as a parameter.

```
public class DevClick implements OnItemClickListener {

    private Activity mActivity;

    public DevClick(Activity activity){
        mAcitvity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
         mActivity.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a constructor of your class DevClick with a argument of you caller activity 
then  you can finish this activity from the event.

```
public DevClick (Context ctx){

   this.context = ctx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call finish() whenever you want.